# Java: Looping through nested JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I have the following structure for storing messages:

```
{
    "Channel_12": [
        ["[{\"to\":\"Bill\",\"msg\":\"Hello\",\"time\":\"10:36\"}]"], "[{\"agentName\":\"demo\",\"msg\":\"Hello 2\",\"time\":\"10:37\"}]"
    ],
    "Channel_34": [
        ["[{\"to\":\"Bill\",\"msg\":\"Hey 1\",\"time\":\"10:37\"}]"], "[{\"agentName\":\"demo\",\"msg\":\"Hey 2\",\"time\":\"10:38\"}]"
    ] }
```

I'm now trying to loop through and get each message for a given channel, lets say i want to fetch all the messages for channel `Channel_12`.

Currently i have the following code:

```
        org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray c = obj.getJSONArray("Channel_12");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i); <!-- Exception is here

            System.out.println(obj.getString("to").toString());
            System.out.println(obj.getString("msg").toString());

        }
```

But am getting the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:277)
    at im.Client$HistoryJSON.getHistory(Client.java:7229)
    at im.Client$32$4.run(Client.java:2246)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you storing escaped JSON within JSON? That makes little sense. If you store it without escaping it, then your code would work i.e. { "Channel_12":[{"to":"Bill"... etc

Answer (score 1):

Chage your code like,

```
        JSONArray c = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Channel_12");  //Change your code from here
        JSONArray array = c.getJSONArray(0);
        String data = c.getString(1);
        Log.i("#Values", array.getString(0) + "\t" + data);
```

See my result,

[image]

Comment: This fixes the sample, hence I upvoted, but really the sample is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `JSONArray` contains a `JSONArray` and a `JSONObject`. A `JSONArray` is **not** a `JSONObject`.

Are you in control of the source format? Because it looks a little weird.

The structure is as so:
At position 0 is an array with one object, and a position 1 is an object.

Your code can be changed to this:

```
org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray c = obj.getJSONArray("Channel_12");
JSONArray array = c.getJSONArray(0);
JSONObject obj2 = array.getJSONObject(0);

System.out.println(obj2.getString("to").toString());
System.out.println(obj2.getString("msg").toString());
```

Comment: Getting: `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONArray.`

Comment: Can you prettyprint the c variable and see what it thinks is in it?

Comment: How can i accomplish that?

Comment: I suppose just clicking on it in the debugger would get you the info you need.