# Getting data from JSON Array

Tags: json

my JSON response is as given below
JSON response is

`{"code":201,"message":[["TEST Action","NA","30-11--2011"],["TEST Action 2","NA","30-11--2011"]]}.`

i want to take the data correspond to 'message'.i used JSON Array.and got response as
JSON  array response is

`[["TEST Action","NA","30-11--2011"],["TEST Action 2","NA","30-11--2011"]]`.

Now how can i access each array in that?

Answer (score 0):

You should expand on what you have done, what language you are using, etc. Normally, you should be able to index into the array with the standard notation. In python for example you can do something along the lines of `json_data["message"][0]` to access the first array and `json_data["message"][1]` to access the second.

Comment: in Java or in Android?

Comment: @user3495439 That is an example in python. Once the json data is loaded into a dictionary you can treat it as a python dict.

Comment: in my code i retrieve the data  as jsonResponse.get("message").

Comment: @user3495439 Depending what library you are using and what the method returns, you should be able to index into an array of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

something like :

```
  var d = JSON.parse('{"code":201,"message":[["TEST Action","NA","30-11--2011"],["TEST Action 2","NA","30-11--2011"]]}')
```

and then you can access each array in message part as :

```
  d.message.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj); });
```

Comment: Didn't see your comment for Java/Android before. You can refer to this solution for Java : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20349690/3660930